# jQuery remove multiple inputs then append just one

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<input type="text" name="val1"/>
<input type="text" name="val2"/>

$('.beta-panel input').fadeOut(function(){
    $(this).remove();
    $('.beta-panel').append('<h1>Done</h1>');
});
```

I have the above code where when a button is clicked it runs a fade out and then appends and fades in a `done` tag. The problem is, when it fades and removes the inputs, it shows the same amount of `<h1>` tags as the inputs.

Comment: Can you post your HTML markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$('.beta-panel').append('<h1>Done</h1>');
```

do:

```
$(this).closest('.beta-panel').append('<h1>Done</h1>');
```

`$(this)` holds reference to the clicked element and `.closest` will find the `.beta-panel` which is closest to `$(this)` and then it appends.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `.promise()` in this case:

```
$('.beta-panel input').fadeOut(function(){
   $(this).remove();
}).promise().done(function(){
   $('.beta-panel').append('<h1>Done</h1>');
});
```

---

From the documentation:

#### [**`.promise()`**](http://api.jquery.com/promise/)

> Description: Return a Promise object to observe when all actions of a
> certain type bound to the collection, queued or not, have finished.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like :

```
$('.beta-panel input').fadeOut(function(){
    $(this).remove();

}).parent().append('<h1>Done</h1>');
```